# How to resolve duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class error

Tags: android

I'm using the Linkedin API with the volley+Fb and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'
```

Here is my Gradle file:

```
multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'}}}dependencies {compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:10.2.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.4') {
    exclude group: 'io.card'
}
compile project(path: ':linkedin-sdk')}
```

Comment: Hi this is stackoverflow, learn [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Im using Volley library with linkedIn sdk that time I'm facing this issue.

Comment: this is not the correct way to ask something, please edit this properly or delete this question and start over. Refer also the link i provided you

Comment: R u add the volley library in gradle else check you volley version

Comment: Im using Volley library and  linkedIn sdk both same time so  I'm facing this issue.I don't know i can resolve it .

Comment: @RajeshwariYadav please show your `build.gradle`

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android { compileSdkVersion 25 buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {applicationId "app.dockedinpatient.com.dockedinpatient"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {release {minifyEnabled false proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }}}

Comment: @RajeshwariYadav add total `build.gradle` & edit this question section

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya may u tell me how i can show my full code of build .gradle file.Im new in this so don't know to attach code.

Comment: @Raj , yeah i have added

Comment: attach your code  this question

Comment: @Rajeswari  copy the code, 4 spaces and paste the code then send

Comment: @Raj unable to send code :(

Comment: @Raj may u provide ur email ?

Comment: @raji why u want my email, I thing error occurs in sending then every line add 4 spaces

Comment: @Raj So i can share my both buid files (linkedIn -sdk build.gradle and app)